# Transform Excel Headers to List of Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to transform a group of columns (table 1) to consolidated rows (table 2), just like the following image:[image: Columns are transformed to list of rows]

I have a larger database, with 24 of these 'to be transformed' columns and many initial rows (around 10k). I've made a VBA code for that, but I'm not actually satisfied with my copy and paste solution.

What would be a good solution for this? Is it actually necessary to use VBA?

*Ps: I want my data to be like table 2 because it's easier to control my data like this. Does that make sense? ( E.g.: If I want to sumifs all the 'Values' that have a 'Name' equals to John that have 'Month' equals to Feb or Mar )*

Comment: Why don't you post what you've tried so far as a starting point and say what you're having issues with

Comment: Since there is no built in function in Excel to do this you would need to write a VBA code I think. Give it a try and come back if you got stuck or errors, and ask a specific question to your code then.

Comment: Thank you Peh, I wasn't sure if there was a built in function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the two ranges (Input and Output) and have a look at the example below. Any questions feel free to ask. You will lose your colouring but I'd put this on with Conditional Formatting instead instead of programatically setting the colours of each ID

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TranposeData()
    Dim InputArr As Variant, OutputArr As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim OutputRow As Long

    ' Update this to your input range
    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    End With

    InputArr = rng.Value2

    ReDim OutputArr(1 To UBound(InputArr, 1) * UBound(InputArr, 2), 1 To 3)

    OutputRow = LBound(OutputArr, 1)

    For j = LBound(InputArr, 2) + 1 To UBound(InputArr, 2)
        For i = LBound(InputArr, 1) + 1 To UBound(InputArr, 1)
            OutputArr(OutputRow, 1) = InputArr(i, 1)
            OutputArr(OutputRow, 2) = InputArr(1, j)
            OutputArr(OutputRow, 3) = InputArr(i, j)
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
        Next i
    Next j

    ' Update this to your output range
    Sheet1.Cells(2, 13).Resize(UBound(OutputArr, 1), UBound(OutputArr, 2)).Value2 = OutputArr
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks. What a gread code Tom, my code was about three times bigger than that. I was working just with  ranges not arrays. Thank you.